# CSS background gradient not working as expected

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I plan on having 3 stripes on a DIV, but this isn't working as expected:

https://jsfiddle.net/1wzg0xep/

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 33%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 34%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

If I make the 2 colors 50%, it works, but having 3 colours just creates a solid colour. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you want something like this: `background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(18,61,87, 1) 34%, rgba(0,0,0, 0.6) 67%, rgba(18,61,87, 1) 100%);`?

Answer (score 5):

**Reason:**

The percentages in the gradient definition specifies the color stop points and not the length/duration of each color. <strike>So, it should be 0% for first color, 33/34% for second color (in the middle), 67% for second color (in the middle) and 100% for the 3rd if you are ***looking for a 3 color gradient***.</strike>

When you specify it as `linear-gradient(to top, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 33%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 34%)`, it means `rgba(18, 61, 87, 1)` till ***34%*** mark and then `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)` from ***33%*** mark (which won't show up because previous color is applied till ***34%*** mark and the next color starts at ***34%***) and then it has `rgba(18, 61, 87, 1)` from ***34%*** till the ***end*** which is the same as first color and so you will end up seeing a solid color only.

---

**Why two colors with 50% works?:**

It would work when you give 50% for both because that would produce a ***hard-stop gradient*** where the first color ends sharp at 50% and second color starts sharp from 50% to 100%. So it would look like there are two segments.

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

---

**Producing a 3 Color Gradient:**

Actually if you ***need a 3 color gradient*** then the correct approach is to set the color stops at 0%, 50% and 100%. This would mean the color starts at  `rgba(18, 61, 87, 1)`, slowly changes from this color to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)` and complete the change at 50%, then again start to change from that color to `rgba(18, 61, 87, 1)` and complete that change at 100%.

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

---

**Producing 3 Stripes:** (I think this is what you need)

If you ***need three stripes and not gradients***, then you need more color stops like here

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 67%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 67%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, try this CSS

```
     #box {
        background: #123d57;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #123d57 0%, #123d57 33%, #000000 34%, #000000 65%, #123d57 66%, #123d57 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #123d57 0%,#123d57 33%,#000000 34%,#000000 65%,#123d57 66%,#123d57 100%); 
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #123d57 0%,#123d57 33%,#000000 34%,#000000 65%,#123d57 66%,#123d57 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#123d57', endColorstr='#123d57',GradientType=0 ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #box {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: #123d57;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%, rgba(18, 61, 87, 1) 100%);
            filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#123d57', endColorstr='#123d57', GradientType=0)
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You an generate similar CSS Gradients [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 0):

Well hopefully this code below will help for you. Good luck!!

```
#box{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background: #123d57;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #123d57 33%, #123d57 34%, #000000 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #123d57 33%,#123d57 34%,#000000 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #123d57 33%,#123d57 34%,#000000 50%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#123d57', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions given above worked for me, as I was trying to convert the `html to pdf`. Background gradient in the `PDF` was visible in some softwares but not on others. So, as a work-around I had to use an top-to-bottom gradient image which I could repeat in the background-image.
I hope someone with my kind of requirement finds this work-around useful.